# Can I use ggvis or shiny to manually (visually) classify points and store the outcome in a new variable?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a time series of indoor temperature measurements that I need to classify into heating and non-heating episodes. I applied a classification algorithm and it worked in most cases. The cases where it misclassified is easy to spot on a scapperplot with the class as color.

It looks similar to this:

```
library(ggvis)
all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0(names(x), ": ", format(x), collapse = "<br />")
}

mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% layer_points(fill = ~factor(am)) %>% add_tooltip(all_values, "click")
```

Except that I need a way to change the value of the variable "am" and store it

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Instead of just seeing information when I click on a point I want to be able to edits its value. Specifically the factor variable represented hete by factor(am)